# R find group with missing rows, create new rows using existing data

Tags: r, dplyr

Here is a simplified version of a problem that involves processing a large, complex table. Here is the input table:

```
library(tidyverse)
input <- tribble(
  ~group, ~score, ~label,
  1, 10, 'A',
  1, 20, 'B',
  1, 30, 'C',
  1, 40, 'D',
  2, 11, 'A',
  2, 21, 'B',
  2, 31, 'C',
  2, 41, 'D',
  3, 12, 'A',
  3, 22, 'B',
  4, 13, 'A',
  4, 23, 'B',
  4, 33, 'C',
  4, 43, 'D'
)
```

The table has 14 rows. The data are grouped in numbered groups (1:4), each group is supposed to have four scores labeled A, B, C, D.
The problem is group 3, which is missing the C and D rows.

I want R to do the following:

1. Find group 3 based on its lack of C and D rows.
2. Insert C and D rows for group 3, in proper alphabetical sequence.
3. Populate `score` in the new C and D rows with the value of of `score` (22) from group 3 row B.

Another way of describing the transformation is that I want two insert two copies of row 3B, changing the label
of those copied rows from B to C and D, respectively.

The desired output table has 16 rows and looks like this:

```
output <- tribble(
  ~group, ~score, ~label,
  1, 10, 'A',
  1, 20, 'B',
  1, 30, 'C',
  1, 40, 'D',
  2, 11, 'A',
  2, 21, 'B',
  2, 31, 'C',
  2, 41, 'D',
  3, 12, 'A',
  3, 22, 'B',
  3, 22, 'C',
  3, 22, 'D',
  4, 13, 'A',
  4, 23, 'B',
  4, 33, 'C',
  4, 43, 'D'
)
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: One idea: reshape wide to get missing values, then reshape long. Finally, fill in missing values with previously non-missing value by group. Look for 'locf' for that part.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
complete(input, group, label) %>%
  fill(score)

# A tibble: 16 x 3
   group label score
   <dbl> <chr> <dbl>
 1     1 A        10
 2     1 B        20
 3     1 C        30
 4     1 D        40
 5     2 A        11
 6     2 B        21
 7     2 C        31
 8     2 D        41
 9     3 A        12
10     3 B        22
11     3 C        22
12     3 D        22
13     4 A        13
14     4 B        23
15     4 C        33
16     4 D        43
```

Comment: Thanks to both for your answers. I think Jon Spring's approach will work, I just haven't quite figured out how to implement it on the larger, more complex table. Will report back when I do.

Comment: I was able to implement Jon Spring's method successfully and transform the large table in the way that I wanted to. I ran into a problem at first, but after stepping through the code I realized that in the large table `group` was a grouped variable, and `complete()` and `fill()` did not like to be fed grouped data. It didn't throw an error, it just didn't create new rows and populate them until I applied `ungroup()` to the table.